# How to shrink the size of a div background image without cropping it?

Tags: html, css

In order to make a div background image responsive, I've tried a lot of techniques like `object-fit: cover`, and using the `padding-top` technique, but the problem is I want the image to shrink when changing the viewport size without being cropped, and without having padding inside it since I want to place elements inside.
I appreciate your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are saying. When I want to control the background size of a div I use "background-size: 150%;" You can play around with this to see what you like. Here is an example of what I have done in the past:

```
#cardImage1 {
  background-image: url("../images/vegetebles.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 185%; /*take not of the background size, it is over 100% */
  background-position: center;
  width: 350px;
  height: 400px;
  transition: 0.7s;
}
```